# Mac: installing homebrew messed up .profile in terminal

Tags: terminal, bash, homebrew

I was following this tutorial https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.13-high-sierra to download Rails.

Upon completed this tutorial, I noticed that my terminal's color code, alias, display format when doing "`ls`" are all messed up.

My `.profile` worked before and it is rather simple.

```
  1 alias alias1="Somalis"
  2 alias mysql="mysql -u root -p"
  3 export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
  4 alias py="python3"
  5 
  6 export CLICOLOR=1;
  7 export LSCOLORS=exfxcxdxbxegedabagacad;
  8 
  9 # Setting PATH for Python 3.6
 10 # The original version is saved in .profile.pysave
 11 PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
 12 export PATH
```

My `.bash_profile` is rather simple as well:

```
 if which rbenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(rbenv init -)"; fi
```

But apparently nothing in my `.profile` works after the installation.

Answer (score 1):

From the bash manual:

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with  the  --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that  order,  and reads  and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The --noprofile option may be used when the shell is started to inhibit this behavior."

As stated if you have the file `~/.bash_profile` then the file `~/.profile` will not be read.

To fix, just run

```
cat .bash_profile >> .profile
rm .bash_profile
```

and open a new Terminal tab.